# jqPlot on jquery mobile page

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am trying to use jqplot in my jquery mobile application, but despite debbuger doesn't show any errors nothing is being displayed.

Here are my libs

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
<!-- CSS LIBS -->
<link href="lib/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery/themes/rw.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="lib/jquery/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="lib/jquery.jqplot.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="lib/jquery/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="lib/jquery.mobile.datepicker.css" />
<!-- JS LIBS -->
<script src="lib/energize-min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.jsonp-2.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.base64.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<!-- JQPLOT LIBS I ADDED -->
<script src="lib/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
```

After Ajax call I want display a chart. Here is my jqMobile page:

```
<div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#rapParam" data-ajax="false" id="rapParamLink" >Params</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#rapSumm" data-ajax="false">Summ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#rapDetails" data-ajax="false">Details</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="rapParam">
            </div>

            <div id="rapSumm">
                <div id="chart" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rapDetails">
                <h1>3 tab contents</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

And here is my function:

```
$.jsonp({
    url: url
    success: function(data, status) {
       $.jqplot('chart',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]);
 },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        errorConnection();
    }
});
```

And after $.jqplot function is called my example chart isn't displayed. Am I missing something?

Comment: do you have your jQuery wrapped in $(document).ready(function(){}) ?

Comment: You mean my function? It is called from button